# Interface link is not up, do not pull packets yet

Tags: mojave, startup, performance

My Mac Mini was working fine till about 3-4 days ago (which is when I last logged in to it). When I tried logging in yesterday it was frozen with the rainbow beach ball mouse pointer. So I powered it off and powered on and since then it comes up to the Apple logo and the white line beneath goes all the way to the end and just stays there.

I went into recovery mode, did a first aid on the disk and tried restoring from an older snapshot. Nothing has helped. Pressing Shift during boot up to go into Single User Mode does nothing. And pressing Cmd+V or Cmd+S during boot shows me messages. They start off fine and somewhere along the way the above "Interface link is not up, do not pull packets yet" messages start appearing, and after about 5 mins that's all there's on the screen. The messages haven't stopped, and even after an hour or more they are still coming. So it looks like the Mac is stuck coz of whatever this message means.

Any suggestions on what I can do here? This machine is running macOS Mojave with the latest updates.

Thanks.

Comment: this looks bad. All "reactions" so far seem to come from the "EFI partition" and not from anything on the disk.
To me it seems possible that your main disk has died.
While you were in the Recovery Partition you have done a FirstAid: did that end in disk OK? If yes, that is strange.
As far as I know there is a Diagnosis mode: look here what and how to do:
https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202731
Tell us the result.

Comment: Thanks for the link. I ran the diagnostics mode but it showed no error. Finally I called Apple. They suggested doing a reinstall from the Recovery Mode. That didn't help either. Next they suggested wiping the drive and then doing a reinstall. That did the trick. So it looks like something wrong with the data on the drive. They said I could try doing a restore from a time machine backup now if I want to, but there is a risk that the problem could recur. So better to just restore individually whatever I want.